# Como configurar o IIS no servidor para Windows Authentication (via Active Directory) de uma aplicação AspNet Core C#?

Tags: asp.net-identity, deploy, asp-net-core, iis

Senhores,

Possuo uma aplicação muito similar ao template pronto do visual studio 2019. Nela, através do 'Users.Identity.Name', obtenho os dados do AD do usuário autenticado conforme abaixo:

```
 public UserIdentityModel GetADUser(ClaimsPrincipal pUser)
    {
        UserIdentityModel user = null;

        try
        {
            using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, _dominio))
            {
                var result = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, _Usuario);

                user = new UserIdentityModel
                {
                    DisplayName = result.DisplayName,
                    Email = result.EmailAddress,
                    Autenticado = pUser.Identity.IsAuthenticated,
                    UserName = result.UserPrincipalName,
                    Groups = result.GetGroups()
                };

                return user;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return user;
        }
    }
```

Minha aplicação está configurada para windows authentication:

```
            services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
```

Meu launchSettings.json

```
  "iisSettings": {
"windowsAuthentication": true,
"anonymousAuthentication": true,
"iisExpress": {
  "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:50437",
  "sslPort": 0
}
```

}

Também está configurado para executar no IIS:

```
        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseIISIntegration();
```

Após publicar essa aplicação e **subir localmente no IIS**, habilitando no IIS as configurações de Windows Authentication e Anonymous Authentication

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Minha aplicação funcionou conforme esperado.
>   O esperado é que ao acessar a URL da aplicação, meu usuário seja carregado
>   automaticamente, sem que seja necessário fornecer informações de
>   usuário e senha.
>   Fiz o teste com outros usuários e máquinas distintas (no mesmo AD que meu usuário) e o resultado foi positivo.

Porém quando subi a aplicação em um IIS do Servidor, que está em um AD diferente do meu, minha aplicação solicita que o usuário forneça as credenciais:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Outro detalhe importante é que eu dei permissões de segurança do IIS a um usuário do mesmo domínio do servidor, mas o comportamento foi o mesmo, sendo necessário fornecer as credenciais.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Finalmente a questão aqui é... Oq preciso fazer para que minha
>   aplicação do servidor se comporte da mesma maneira que minha aplicação
>   local?

Comment: provavelmente seu usuário é administrador da máquina local, por isso funciona tudo bem, agora se está logando num servidor fora da sua máquina é normal se comportar diferente, precisa adicionar seu usuário ou um grupo que faça parte nas permissões do IIS. E quando disse "AD diferente do meu" vc quer dizer outro domínio?

Comment: Ricardo, eu testei dar permissões a um usuário porém a aplicação ainda solicita credenciais. E sim, quando digo AD diferente do meu, são domínios diferentes. 
Seu comentário tem um peso importante que eu deveria tê-lo deixado mais claro na pergunta.